# Mocking controllerFor in qunit tests.

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ember.js, qunit, ember-qunit

I have a mixin that helps me get through a workflow of steps. Basically it looks at what the current step is and then does some magic based on that. The issue is that the first line of the function grabs `this.controllerFor('document')` and I don't understand how to mock that `controllerFor` call. I know that I can, for example, pass `{testing: "123"}` into the `.create` in the test. This will then give me `this.get('testing')` but how do I mock the `controllerFor`? Also, to be clear, the only reason for the controllerFor call is so that I can get the `currentStep`.

**prepare-next.js**

```
setNext: function() {
    let currentStep = this.controllerFor('document').get('currentStep');

    if (currentStep === 'First_step') {
        //do something
    } else {
        //do something else...
    }
    // Bunch more stuff happens...
}
```

**prepare-next-test.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import PrepareNext from 'my-app/mixins/prepare-next';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('mixin:prepare-next');

const PrepareNextObject = Ember.Object.extend(PrepareNext);
let subject;


test('#setNext does all the things', function(assert) {
  subject = PrepareNextObject.create();
  subject.setNext();
  //assert.equal(foo, bar);
});
```

Comment: what assertions do you want to make? you can use sinon.js if you simply to assert that a given function was called with specific arguments. otherwise, i find that acceptance tests are a more appropriate level of testing for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `controllerFor` method before or in test:

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import PrepareNext from '../../../mixins/prepare-next';
import { module, test } from 'qunit';

module('mixin:prepare-next');

const PrepareNextObject = Ember.Object.extend(PrepareNext);

let subject;

test('#setNext does all the things', function(assert) {
  assert.expect(2);

  subject = PrepareNextObject.create();
  subject.controllerFor = () => {
    assert.ok(true, 'controllerFor called');
    return {
      get() {
        assert.ok(true, 'Get called');
        return 'First_step';
      }
    }
  };
  subject.setNext();
  //assert.equal(foo, bar);
});
```

[Working demo.](https://ember-twiddle.com/4c82052fb8e83178bcd5dd2acd10891b?numColumns=2&openFiles=tests.unit.mixins.prepare-next-test.js%2Cmixins.prepare-next.js)